# Export JavaFX project with Apache Derby Embedded database into a executable file using eclipse

Tags: maven, javafx, derby

I have created a JavaFX project with an Apache Derby embedded database. Now I want to distribute it to a client. I would like to create an executable file, possibly .exe. How can I achieve it? Is there a tutorial I can follow?

I have tried Maven but after I have created an executable it does not export other libraries such as JavaFX & derby.jar, derbyshared.jar and derbytools.jar required for the project to work.

Comment: Study the [packaging resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) in the JavaFX tag.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this demo project here: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX It uses jpackage, jlink and jdeps to create app bundles and installers.